# Two classes XMLDeserializer and XMLSerializer methods

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

Two cs files. Use the same namespace.
Class A / Class B, structure is different.
Using the A class as a dictionary  mAclass = new Dictionary  ()
I am using XMLDeserializer and XMLSerializer.
I want to treat XMLDeserializer and XMLSerializer as A and B in common.
However, the structure of Class A and Class B is different.
How do I use Class A and Class B together?
(I'm a C # beginner.)

Comment: it would be great if you could share some of your code

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XmlIncludeAttribute` tag to do what you want, I think.
Something like this:

```
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(A))]
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(B))]
class AorB
{
}

class A : AorB
{
}

class B : AorB
{
}


class ToSerialize
{
    public AorB MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

You could create a common base class instead of using `object` to be more specific.

Without seeing more code, it's hard to address the question more specifically.